# Lists of figures and table - Print "Figure X.Y - "

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I want to customize my lists of figures and tables so that it looks like this:

```
Figure 1.1 - Name of the fig.
Figure 1.2 - etc.
```

I am currently using the `tocloft` package and managed to have

```
Figure 1.1 Name 1
Figure 1.2 etc
```

with the code :

```
 \documentclass{book}  
 \usepackage{tocloft}
 \renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{F\textsc{igure} }
 \renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{T\textsc{ableau} }
 \begin{document}
 \listoffigures
 \begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{center}
        % My fig
        \caption{Test 1}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

but I miss the dash (which appear in the regular caption in the main corpus by the way).

Any idea of how to do that ?

Comment: Please post the code which you have managed to get. It will be easy for potential answerers to start with.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: Please post a MWE: http://goo.gl/dtPzv. It starts from `\documentclass{...}` and ends at `\end{document}`. ;)

Comment: Edited again ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\cftfigaftersnum` as

```
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{~~--}
```

I am not sure of whether you want page numbers or not. If not, add this also:

```
\cftpagenumbersoff{figure}
```

Code:

```
 \documentclass{book}
 \usepackage{tocloft}
 \renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\textsc{Figure} }
 \renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{\textsc{Tableau} }
 \renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{~~--}
 \renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{~~--}
 %% \cftpagenumbersoff{figure}  %% If you don't want page numbers
 %% \cftpagenumbersoff{table}  %% If you don't want page numbers
 \begin{document}
 \listoffigures
 \listoftables
 \begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
        % My fig
        \caption{Test 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[h]
 \centering
        % My tab
        \caption{Test 1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your example looks exactly like what I want. Unfortunately, I must have an incompatible package somewhere because my caption in the lof is sometimes above the dash. I can't really post my whole preambule (more than 130 lines). Are there any known incompatible package with locloft ?

Comment: (Can't comment above) It seems that it's overlaying when the title is too long. Just for you to know...

Comment: @Basil Difficult to say without knowing what packages you are loading. That is why we ask for a MWE. Try removing packages one by one until the error vanishes. Regarding overlaying, it is again difficult to say without more details!

Comment: I figured out the problem and it's not related to any package. The key is that in the lof the length between (for instance) "FIGURE 1 - " and the title itself is fixed. It means that the distance is just ok for "figure 1 -" it will not work for "Figure 11.24 -" (4 more characters that make the layout). The solution is then to raise this fixed distance with "\renewcommand{\cftXnumwidth}{4em}" (X is fig or tab).

Comment: @Basil Glad you have found it. But How do I/we know that you have a figure number `11.24`? ;-)